# How to change UAA log level from DEBUG to INFO?

Tags: cloudfoundry-uaa

I am using UAA "cloudfoundry-identity-uaa-4.14.0.war" and could see there are no where i can change the log level. Few places i have changed but that does not work. Even tried using the latest version which is 4.30.0, but still it doesn't work. Can anyone please suggest some solutions?

Answer (score 0):

`uaa.logging_level` appears to be in reference to a property supported by the [BOSH release](https://bosh.io/jobs/uaa?source=github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa-release&version=73.7.0#p%3Duaa.logging_level). There is no direct equivalent in the UAA.